# Scala pairs using map and flatten

Tags: list, scala, mapping, flatten

I'm working on a problem to take two lists, for example (1,2,3) and (a,b) and return a list ((1,a)(1,b)(2,a)(2,b)(3,a)(3,b)) using only map and flatten.

This problem requires me to define a function as follows:

```
def product[A](xs: List[A], ys: List[A])= {
```

And within this function get the result. I'm rather new to Scala and I am used to languages like python and java.

I've gotten this far:

```
def product[A](xs: List[A], ys: List[A])= {  
    for(y <- ys){
   println(xs.map(x=> (x,y)))  
    }
  }
```

This will return something like this:

List((1,a), (2,a), (3,a))

List((1,b), (2,b), (3,b))

I'm not sure how can combine these lists now. In python I would do something like create a new list variable, append both of these lists to that list, and then flatten it so I would have one list. However, I'm rather confused by scala as it seems as if I am not allowed to define a new variable within a function. How can I combine these lists and flatten them at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it using *for comprehension*. It's actually a [syntactic sugar](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html) for `map` and `flatMap`:

```
def product[A](xs: List[A], ys: List[A])= {
    for {
      x <- xs
      y <- ys
    } yield {
      x -> y
    }
}
```

For-comprehensions is the Scala idiomatic way to achieve this. It's more readable and maintainable, and the underlying operations are still `map` and `flatMap`. In fact, even for types that are not collections, but still have `map` and `flatMap`, it's common to use for comprehensions (`Future`s, `Option`s, `Try`s, etc.)

#### Edit

If you want to continue with your solution and save the lists and combine them, you'll have to drop the `println` and add a `yield`, and then flatten the main list that was created:

```
def product[A](xs: List[A], ys: List[A]) = {
  for (y <- ys) yield {
    xs.map(x => (x, y))
  }
}

val res = product(List(1, 2, 3), List("a", "b"))

println(res.flatten)
```

Comment: Thank you all for the answers! My question about my solution: Right now i'm simply printing those lists. How can I save them so that I can reference them and combine them?

Answer (score 2):

Product List using only map and flatten

```
val nums = List(1, 2, 3)
val chars = List('a', 'b')

nums.map { a => chars.map { b => (a, b) } }.flatten
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> nums.map(a => chars.map(b => (a, b)))
res5: List[List[(Int, Char)]] = List(List((1, 'a'), (1, 'b')), List((2, 'a'), (2, 'b')), List((3, 'a'), (3, 'b')))
scala> nums.map(a => chars.map(b => (a, b))).flatten
res6: List[(Int, Char)] = List((1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'a'), (3, 'b'))
```

Product List can be built using flatMap and map combination

```
nums.flatMap { a => chars.map { b => (a, b) }}
```

Product List can also be built using for comprehension

```
for {a <- nums; b <- chars} yield (a, b)
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> val nums = List(1, 2, 3)
val nums: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val chars = List('a', 'b')
chars: List[Char] = List('a', 'b')

scala> nums.flatMap { a => chars.map { b => (a, b) }}
res2: List[(Int, Char)] = List((1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'a'), (3, 'b'))

scala> for {a <- nums; b <- chars} yield (a, b)
res3: List[(Int, Char)] = List((1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'a'), (3, 'b'))
```

Comment: Thanks! This is great

Answer (score 1):

```
val ls1 = List(1,2,3) 
val ls2 = List('a','b') 
def product[A](xs: List[A], ys: List[A])= xs.map(x => ys.map((x,_))).flatten 

product(ls1,ls2)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. What does the ys.map(x, _ ) do? I thought that map had the syntax ys.map (y=> some_manipulation_of_y). Why can you just say ys.map(x, _ )? I thought it might just be shorthand for ys.map (y => (x,_)) but this gives me some missing parameter type

Comment: You are welcome. Not sure what you mean, but, basically you take each element represented as `x` from outer list (xs) and apply the function ys.map((x,_)) to it. The `_` is just a placeholder for elements of ys. You could also write it without the underscore like this: `xs.map(x => ys.map(y => (x,y))).flatten`